# Using Templated Eigen Matrices in Class

Tags: c++, class, templates, eigen, eigen3

I want to create a class that uses matrices whose types and sizes are determined by the user during the constructor call. I tried to use a class template whose arguments are then used to instantiate everything in the class members, but I'm getting errors.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is my erroring code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "eigen.h"
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

using namespace Eigen;

template<typename type, static const int _numMeas, static const int _numStates>
class pf
{
public:
    pf(const Matrix<type, _numMeas, _numMeas>& _R, const Matrix<type, _numStates, _numStates>& _Q)
    {
    };

private:
    int numMeas   = _numMeas;
    int numStates = _numStates;

    Matrix<type, _numMeas, _numMeas> R;
    Matrix<type, _numStates, _numStates> Q;
};
```

Comment: `Matrix<type, numMeas, numMeas> R` the last two template parameters are not compile time consts. Just use the template params and toss the two int declarations.

Comment: @doug, I'm not sure how to do that since I need to specify the matrix dimensions. Are you suggesting `Matrix<type> R;` and then defining the row/col lengths later? How would that work?

Comment: You can alternatively make your `int` variables `static constexpr` (just `static const` would be sufficient). Or remove these lines from your class and remove the `_` from the template parameters. In either case the dimensions need to be known at compile time.

Comment: @chtz, I decided to try `static const`, but it's still not working (post has updated code), am I missing something?

Comment: @P_B Did you ever program with templates before? You need to put the `static const` in front of the member *variables* (the lines behind `private:` in your case) not in front of the template parameters.